# How do I typedef base class's member template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, allocator

I'm trying to make a short form of `rebind_alloc` as a member template.

The minimal part of my code is as below:

```
template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct A
{
  using allocator_type = Allocator;

  template <class U>
  using rebind_alloc = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<U>;
};

template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct B : A<T, Allocator>
{
  using base = A<T>;
  using typename base::allocator_type;

  B(const allocator_type& alloc);
  // B(const base::allocator_type& alloc);

  template <class U>
  using typename base::rebind_alloc<U>; // ERROR ON THIS LINE
};
```

The reason I wrote every base class's member type is that in the class template inheriting another class template I cannot directly use the member type but use `base::some_type` form.

A single type like `allocator_type` is okay, but I got an error when I try to use `using` statements for the member template.

How do I properly use it?

Comment: Shouldn't the base class be `A<T, Allocator>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are about ten errors in your code. Spot the difference. (Missing semicolons only count as one.)

```
#include <memory>

template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct A
{
  using allocator_type = Allocator;

  template <class U>
  using rebind_alloc =
      typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<U>;
};

template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct B : A<T, Allocator>
{
  using base = A<T, Allocator>;
  using allocator_type = typename base::allocator_type;

  B(const allocator_type& alloc);

  template <class U>
  using rebind_alloc = typename base::template rebind_alloc<U>;
};
```

Comment: What's the difference between `using typename base::allocator_type` and `using allocator_type = typename base::allocator_type`?

Comment: @kukyakya: You'd have to name the base class literally, not via an alias: `using typename A<T, Allocator>::allocator_type;` I can edit it if you prefer that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a new alias template, which uses the base one:

```
template <class U>
  using rebind_alloc = typename base::rebind_alloc<U>;
```